# don't merge table field in join yii2

Tags: join, yii2

I have problem to join 2 table , when I execute blow code the result code correct ,but  don't show pin field from ticket_pin in result

```
 $model = Ticket::find()->leftJoin(TicketPin::tableName(), 'ticket.id=ticket_pin.ticket_id and ticket_pin.user_id=1')->all();

                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [receiver_user_id] => 
                [title] => بسش
                [problem] => شسبس
                [text] => سشب
                [receiver] => 1
                [priority] => 1
                [status] => 4
                [seen] => 
                [online] => 
                [created_at] => 1490588016
```

but when i use createCommand It's shows the result correctly , But I need to use ActiveRecord

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM ticket LEFT JOIN ticket_pin ON ticket.id=ticket_pin.ticket_id and ticket_pin.user_id=1 order by ticket.id DESC')->queryAll();

        [id] => 
        [user_id] => 
        [reciver_user_id] => 1
        [title] => سس
        [problem] => afsfsa
        [text] => sfaaf
        [reciver] => 
        [priority] => 1
        [status] => 4
        [seen] => 0
        [online] => 
        [{"user_id":2,"name":"\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f","time":1491378729}]
        [created_at] => 1491378692
        [ticket_id] => 
        [pin] =>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get `TicketPin` attributes from `Ticket` AR model itself, but you can access `TicketPin` from `Ticket` relation (if you implemented it, or if Gii made it for you).

If Ticket has **many** TicketPins then I think, this kind of query will be correct for your case:

```
$tickets = Ticket::find()->joinWith(['ticketPins' => function(ActiveQuery $query) {
    $query->andWhere(['ticket_pin.user_id' => 1]);
}])->all();

foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    foreach($ticket->ticketPins as $ticketPin) {
        echo $ticketPin->pin //Something like that
    }
}
```

So, explaining this code, you get Ticket models with Eager loaded TicketPins inside (`user_id=1` filtration is included in anonymous function).
Sorry, if the given code contains some errors. I believe you can recheck it and make it useful for your project

Comment: thanks for your soultion i did it but have some problem .
in result I mention in other comment, 
but the problem is 
foreach($tickets as $ticket) {
    echo $ticket->pin //Something like that
}
Getting unknown property: app\models\Ticket::pin

Comment: @mohammad-zahedimohammad Oh.. sorry man, I missed one thing. Right now will update my former answer

Answer (score 2):

By below query you are getting `Ticket` model attributes. if you want to get `TicketPin` model attributes than define them in `Ticket` model.

```
 $model = Ticket::find()->leftJoin(TicketPin::tableName(), 'ticket.id=ticket_pin.ticket_id and ticket_pin.user_id=1')->all();
```

first define attribute in Ticket model class as below :

```
 public $pin; // assuming you need pin attribute
```

Now in query add select statement :

```
 $model = Ticket::find()->select('ticket.*,ticket_pin.pin')->leftJoin(TicketPin::tableName(), 'ticket.id=ticket_pin.ticket_id and ticket_pin.user_id=1')->all();
```

now you can get pin attribute.

-> Second way is taking query output as array, doing this no need to define attributes in model.

```
  $model = Ticket::find()->select('ticket.*,ticket_pin.pin')->leftJoin(TicketPin::tableName(), 'ticket.id=ticket_pin.ticket_id and ticket_pin.user_id=1')->asArray()->all();
```

Comment: thanks for your soultion , it's work correctly 
I dont have permission to like your post